# read and write to an NSMutableArray with Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

This seems to be pretty simple but I just cant seem to find the way to do that anywhere. Basically, I am building an array with dictionaries as follows:

```
NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3pm",@"4pm",@"5pm",nil];
NSDictionary *timesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:times forKey:@"Times"];

NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Miami", @"New York", @"Las Vegas", nil];
NSDictionary *locationsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:locations forKey:@"Locations"];

[listOfItems addObject:timesDict];
[listOfItems addObject:locationsDict];
```

And would like to add dynamically more times and locations based on the user's input.

given that I have new variables that hold a new "time" and a new "location" (both are NSString), how can I add them based on the Times/Locations key?

Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
[listOfItems addObject:newLocation forkey:@"Locations"];
[listOfItems addObject:newTime forkey:@"Times"];
```

(which doesnt compile of course....)

And also read from Locations or Times, like that:

NSString *str =  read from listOfItems, forkey:"Times", atIndex:bla (in free form :))

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use two separate dictionaries?
try using one that contains two arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *times = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"3pm",@"4pm",@"5pm",nil];
NSMutableArray *locations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Miami", @"New York", @"Las Vegas", nil];
NSDictionary *dataDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:times,@"Times",locations,@"Locations",nil];
```

That way you can access your arrays with:

```
[dataDict objectForKey:@"Times"]
```

Or specific time at index:

```
[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Times"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

or add value to Times array:

```
[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Times"] addObject:@"Today"];
```

Comment: BTW, this option seems to crash during run time...[[dataDict objectForKey:@"Times"] addObject:@"Today"];

Comment: my bad..i did not declare the two arrays as Mutable...works now, thanks awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
[[listOfItems locationsDict] addObject:newLocation];
```

and

```
[[listOfItems timesDict] addObject:newTime];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. That could work but will require to make locationsDict and timesDict global. Isnt there a way to read/write based on the Key? Also, how would you READ in this matter? Say, a location in index 3?

Comment: You could do something like: [[myDictionary objectAtIndex:] valueForKey:] to read the data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create instances of NSMutableArray / NSMutableDictionary. After that, you can use the methods Dylan Reich suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good time to use a class to represent your times and locations. It would be easier to manage and easier for a new programmer on the project to understand.

```
@interface TimesAndLocations : NSObject
{
    //Initialize these in init and release in dealloc
    NSMutableArray *_times;
    NSMutableArray *_locations;
}

//Use these methods to add times and locations
-(void)addTime:(NSString*)time;
-(void)addLocation:(NSString*)location;

//Could add remove methods here as well

@end
```